# Use multiple images for each variation

Tags: woocommerce

How can I use multiple images for each variation and display only the variation images on attribute selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign only one image per variation in default WooCommerce plugin, still other plugins are present that provides you to assign multilple images to each variation that can be found in wordpress.org or codecanyon.net. And also don't forget to check their compatibility with your theme as many plugins supports only woocommerce template structure and they fail in most of the themes as woocommerce uses flexslider for gallery images but most of the themes uses other sliders like owl carousel, flickity etc.